# Adding button in the body using meteor and get the value from JS function

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is my requirement.

When I click the button from HTML, it
should call one method from JavaScript. That method has to
return one value that I can print in the HTML page.

Please advise.

```
<body>
<button class="test"> TEST !!!</button>
<li>{{test}}</li> // This value keep on change when i click the button
</body> 

 JS:Template.body.events({
'click .test': function ()
 {
 userName=random value;
 return userName;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <button class="test"> TEST !!!</button>
  <p>{{test}}</p> // This value keep on change when i click the button
</body>
```

JS:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  test: function() {
    return Session.get('randomValue');
  }
});

Template.body.events({
  'click .test': function(evt, tpl) {
    Session.set('randomValue', (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0));
  }
});
```

I recommend you to check out Meteor's official tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app

**EDIT**: You can do it without using global Session variable. You can use `reactive-var` package.

Add reactive-var package into your project:

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

Your JS file:

```
function generateRandomNum() {
  return (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
}

Template.body.onCreated(function() {
  //set default value of reactive var
  this.randomValue = new ReactiveVar(generateRandomNum());
});

Template.body.helpers({
  test: function() {
    return Template.instance().randomValue.get();
  }
});

Template.body.events({
  'click .test': function(evt, tpl) {
    tpl.randomValue.set(generateRandomNum());
  }
});
```

Read more about scoped reactivity: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity

Read more about ReactiveVar in the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar

Comment: Yea this is true but we are adding this to Session variable. With out adding this into session variable can we do that ?

Comment: We can also do it using ReactiveVar. I have updated my answer.